# How to get parts of a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this string:

```
   string var = "x1,x2,x3,x4";
```

I want to get x1, x2, x3, x4 separately in four different strings.

Comment: The over-abundant Google results for "C# how to get parts of a string" were not enough? Please, at least try a fast Google search before asking trivial questions.

Comment: Please try to research before you ask here. Anyways, welcome to this site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic split

```
string yourString = "x1,x2,x3,x4";
string[] parts = yourString.Split(',');

foreach(string s in parts)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I renamed the original variable into `yourString`. While it seems that it is accepted in LinqPad as a valid identifier I think that it is very confusing using this name because is reserved

Answer (score 2):

Split it up.

```
var tokens = someString.Split(',');
```

Now you can access them by their index:

```
var firstWord = tokens[0];
```

Comment: Yes a very bad idea calling a variable var, however it seems that it is accepted (at least in LinqPad)

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Appearantly `var` is considered a [contextual keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) and from a few tests those seem to be allowed as variable names in both LINQPad and VS.

Answer (score 1):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var foo = "x1,x2,x3,x4";
var result = foo.Split(',');
```

There's also the "opposite: [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join('*', result));
```

Will output: `x1*x2*x3*x3`

Answer (score 0):

To separate values with comma between them, you can use `String.Split()` function.

```
string[] words = var.Split(',');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```